# why boost::shared_ptr can not be compiled if BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS is defined in user.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

I have an embeded system and would like to use boost in this system, but need to disable exception because I do not want to pay cost of exception.

Boost has given one user.hpp and settable macro option **BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS** and **BOOST_NO_EXCEPTION_STD_NAMESPACE**, but boost::shared_ptr can not be compiled(more precisely speaking, can not be linked) if these two macro is defined.

```
shared_ptr_boost.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail12shared_countC2IiEEPT_[_ZN5boost6detail12shared_countC5IiEEPT_]+0x7a): undefined reference to `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

why does boost give macro options but do not promise compilation with those options?

Answer (score 10):

It can be compiled.

It just cannot be linked.

That is because if you define BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS, you'll have to provide the implementation of `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)` somewhere, to replace the usual error raising facilities.

Have a read through the comments in throw_exception.hpp:

```
namespace boost
{

#ifdef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS

void throw_exception(std::exception const & e); // user defined

#else

//[Not user defined --Dynguss]
template<class E> inline void throw_exception(E const & e)  
{
    throw e;
}

#endif

} // namespace boost
```

Comment: if defined by user, does this function make any sense in case BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS is defined? Who will call it?

Comment: Libraries will call it in case they need to fail. In unhandled exceptional cases... I guess whether it makes sense depends on what errors you leave unhandled and how you implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my final solution.

shared_ptr_boost.cpp:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>

namespace boost{
  void throw_exception(std::exception const &e){}
}
int main(){
  boost::shared_ptr<int> pName(new int(2));
  *pName += 3;
  printf("name = %d\n", *pName);
  return 0;
}
```

compile command:

`arm-hisiv100-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ -I../boost_1_59_0/ -DBOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DBOOST_NO_EXCEPTION_STD_NAMESPACE -fno-exceptions shared_ptr_boost.cpp`

For such a small test program, I get about 1.7K smaller executable file; that's what I do not want to pay for exception.

Comment: The size difference "for such a small program" is irrelevant. It could be still 1.7k for my 90MiB binaries. Also, what did you do? Just ignoring exceptions? I don't want to use that software.